# My while statement is going wacky and I'm not sure what is wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, python-3.1

My code is not working, and I'm not sure what is going on. The problem is when I input "Y" the first time, it still says "Please enter a valid input" and I need to re-enter a second time for it to work.

```
if getoutofbed == "y":
    outofbed = 1
    print("You chose to get out of bed.")
elif getoutofbed == "n":
    outofbed = 2
    print("Your mom disregards your choice and screams at you to get out of bed. Listening to your mother, you step off the ledge of your resting place.")
    print("    .@@@@,")
    print("    aa`@@@,",name.upper(),"I DONT CARE IF YOU DONT WANNA GET UP!")
    print("    =  `@@@ GET UP!")
    print("      )_/`@'")
    print("     / || @")
    print("     | || @")
    print("     /~|| `")
    print("    /__W_/")
    print("      |||")
    print("     _|||")
    print("    ((___)")
    print("")
    print("")
while outofbed != 1 or 2:
    print("Please enter a valid input.")
    print("")
    print("")
    getoutofbed = input("Choose to get out of bed? Y/N").lower()
    print("")
    print("")
    if getoutofbed == "y":
        print("You chose to get out of bed.")
        break
    elif getoutofbed == "n":
        print("    .@@@@,")
        print("    aa`@@@,",name.upper(),"I DONT CARE IF YOU DONT WANNA GET UP!")
        print("    =  `@@@ GET UP!")
        print("      )_/`@'")
        print("     / || @")
        print("     | || @")
        print("     /~|| `")
        print("    /__W_/")
        print("      |||")
        print("     _|||")
        print("    ((___)")
        break
```

Comment: That's because `'y' != 'Y'`

Comment: `outofbed != 1 or 2:` does not work like "if outofbed is one or outofbed is two" like english does...

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your while loop statement.

Even when `outofbed != 1` evaluates to `False`, `2` will evaluate to `True` because it is a "truthy" value. Change it to this:

```
while outofbed != 1 and outofbed != 2:
```

Hope this helps